# Stop Wordpress on Subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a website (http://alvarezpatrick.com) that uses wordpress. I have set up a subdomain (portfolio.alvarezpatrick.com) which I want to use to show example projects, etc. and which I would like not to be part of wordpress. However, if you go to http://portfolio.alvarezpatrick.com it seems to redirect you to http://alvarezpatrick.com, and if you go to http://alvarezpatrick.com/portfolio_html/index.php it seems to say it isn't found.

From looking around I've seen that it should work if I do the following, but unfortunately it does not:

1. Edit the .htaccess in the main public folder by adding:

   `RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?alvarezpatrick\.com$ [nc]`
2. Create a .htaccess in the portfolio.alvarezpatrick.com domain root folder "portfolio_html" with the following single line of code: `RewriteEngine Off`

Comment: your subdomain directory is there in the corresponding folder or not? the errors into your httaccess file , regenerate httaccess file

Comment: Yes there is, but how do I regenerate the htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Your main website is on public_html. To avoid using the wordpress on your sub-domain you can point the sub-domain outside the public_html.

For example:

```
/portfolio/   --- portfolio.example.com
/public_html/ --- example.com
```

Comment: As mentioned in my original post I do have the main page on public_html and the subdomain on portfolio_html